# How can I avoid adding duplicate rows to my list view control?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I have a list view control that I want to add accounts to. The first column of the list view is for an account's username, and the second column is for the account's password.

I want avoid adding duplicate **rows** of login credentials. What I mean by that is that I don't care if a username appears in the list view control more than once. Just as long as each instance of the username has a different password. The same rule applies to passwords. I don't care if multiple accounts have the same password.

I just want to avoid duplicate **ROWS**.

The following code is something I have tried with no success:

```
private void AddAccounts()
{
    List<string> usernames = new List<string>();
    usernames.Add("Margaret Parker");
    usernames.Add("Steven Stewart");
    usernames.Add("Heather Powell");
    usernames.Add("Denise Simmons");
    usernames.Add("Ronald Moore");

    List<string> passwords = new List<string>();
    passwords.Add("mExEvHb3");
    passwords.Add("muFLdtHu");
    passwords.Add("GrcSNCyY");
    passwords.Add("S8qenUZY");
    passwords.Add("PVAzFYyu");

    // usernames.Count will always be the same as passwords.Count
    // so it doesn't matter which property I use.
    for (int i = 0; i < usernames.Count; i++)
    {
        ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(usernames[i]);
        lvi.SubItems.Add(passwords[i]);

        if (!accountsListView.Items.Contains(lvi))
        {
            // It is unsafe to call a control from a thread other
            // than the one that created the control without using
            // the Invoke method.
            Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { accountsListView.Items.Add(lvi); });
        }
    }
}
```

When *AddAccounts()* is called, it will add the following items to *accountsListView*:

```
    /*
    #   Margaret Parker       mExEvHb3
    #   Steven Stewart        muFLdtHu
    #   Heather Powell        GrcSNCyY
    #   Denise Simmons        S8qenUZY
    #   Ronald Moore          PVAzFYyu
    */
```

It will **not** take into consideration if an account has already been added to the list view control. Which is why I'm coming to you folks for help.

## How can I avoid adding duplicate rows to a list view control?

#### Thank you for taking the time to read my question.

**I want to ALLOW multiple instances of the same username OR password:**

```
    /*
    #   JamesEdwards ---- LZsDVQ7A ---- different password (GOOD!)
    #   GeraldLopez  ---- LZsDVQ7A    
    #   JamesEdwards ---- 7cbrPRzt ---- different password (GOOD!)
    */
```

**I want to avoid EXACT duplicates:**

```
    /*
    #   PhillipAnderson ---- 4ZN5TKfM ---- exact duplicate (BAD!)
    #   NicholasPowell  ---- 4ZN5TKfM    
    #   PhillipAnderson ---- 4ZN5TKfM ---- exact duplicate (BAD!)
    */
```

If an account's password ever gets changed, then I want to be able to add that account **again** to my list view control with the new password. I want to keep the old account information in my list view control as well. That is why I want to allow duplicate usernames in my list view control.

Comment: So you need the userNames to be unique in `usernames` list?

Comment: Bad design!! UserName should be unique

Comment: @KosalaW The usernames list can include duplicates. The passwords list can include duplicates as well. I just don't want the list view control to contain duplicate rows.

Comment: It looks like your just comparing the instances and not the values with accountsListView.Items.Contains(lvi).  You need to compare the individual fields with a Comparator or directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a new instance of `ListViewItem` and validating existence in the collection, which performs reference check and returns `false` all the time.

instead of this `accountsListView.Items.Contains(lvi)`

do this

```
ListViewItem item = accountsListView.FindItemWithText(userNames[i]);

if (item == null)
{
    // logic goes here.
}
```

or

```
bool found = false;
foreach(ListViewItem lv in accountsListView.Items)
{
    if(lv.Text ==userNames[i]) 
    {
        found = true; 
        break;
    }
}

if(!found)
{
     // logic goes here.   
}
```

Make a note `ListView` also provides [`FindItemWithText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.finditemwithtext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to validate existence of an item.

Comment: `if (!accountsListView.Items.Any(l => lvi.Text == usernames[i]))
                {
                    Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { accountsListView.Items.Add(lvi); });
                }`

'ListView.ListViewItemCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Any' and no extension method 'Any' accepting a first argument of type 'ListView.ListViewItemCollection' could be found

Comment: Add namespace `using System.Linq;`

Comment: I already did, and got that error. I should have mentioned that.

Comment: 'ListView.ListViewItemCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Any' and the best extension method overload 'Queryable.Any<ListViewItem>(IQueryable<ListViewItem>, Expression<Func<ListViewItem, bool>>)' requires a receiver of type 'IQueryable<ListViewItem>'

Comment: I missed the point, ListViewItemCollection doesn't implement iqueryable inteface, so we can't run all Linq statements.

Comment: I guess you can also do this `accountsListView.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>().Any(l => lvi.Text == usernames[i])`. try and let me know. I will update the answer accordingly.

Comment: **I want to allow multiple instances of the same username in my list view control.** I DON'T want to allow multiple instances of the same username **AND** password.

Comment: Identify the key that uniquely distinguish ListViewItem.

Answer (score 0):

There are few things that you need to change in your code. You do not have to use 2 lists for this purpose. One list should be enough. You can use available features in C# to do this kind of things more efficiently.

So as the first step; create a class and inherit it from `IEqualityComparer`. We have to override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods to make it possible to be used in Linq etc.

```
    public class UserAccount : IEqualityComparer<UserAccount>
    {
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }

        public bool Equals(UserAccount x, UserAccount y)
        {
            return (x.UserName == y.UserName && x.Password == y.Password);
        }

        public int GetHashCode(UserAccount obj)
        {
            return obj.UserName.GetHashCode() + obj.Password.GetHashCode();
        }
    }
```

Then use the above created class to create a `List` of user accounts.

```
       var userAccounts = new List<UserAccount>
       {
           new UserAccount() {UserName = "PhillipAnderson", Password = "4ZN5TKfM"},
           new UserAccount() {UserName = "NicholasPowell", Password = "4ZN5TKfM"},
           new UserAccount() {UserName = "PhillipAnderson", Password = "4ZN5TKfM"}
       };
```

Now you can use `Distinct` method to filter out duplicate user accounts. you will notice `uniqueUserAccounts` has only 2 user accounts after applying `Distinct`.

```
        var uniqueUserAccounts = userAccounts.Distinct(new UserAccount()).ToList();

        foreach (var uniqueUserAccount in uniqueUserAccounts)
        {
            //your code to add user accounts to the list view
        }
```